# Autoscroll was but now isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on a project that, when you click the page, it scrolls the entire length of the page.  But it does this at 20px intervals; this is to allow javascript to be executed while scrolling in iOS.

However, when uploading the final version, my ftp client has deleted some of the code and it's now not working.  I can't see why.

Any suggestions?

```
var t;
var scrolling = false;

// doScroll sets the position in which to auto pause.
function doScroll() {
    $('body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop() + 20);
    if($("#pause").offset().top >=300 && $("#pause").offset().top < 304){
        ScrollIt();    
    } else 
    if($("#pause").offset().top >=4000 && $("#pause").offset().top < 4004){
        ScrollIt() ;   
    } else
    if($("#pause").offset().top >=7500 && $("#pause").offset().top < 7504){
        ScrollIt()  ;  
    }
}

// ScrollIt removes the interval for scrolling, pausing the scroll.
function ScrollIt() {
    clearInterval(t);
    scrolling = false;
        return; 
//        playPause()
}

//Stop/start on click
$('#pause').on('click',function(){
    ScrollIt();
    scrolling = !scrolling;
    if(!scrolling){ 
        clearInterval(t);
        return;
    }
    t = setInterval(doScroll, 5);
});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console while executing this script. Please also include them with your question

Comment: also please paste whole of your script here. i cannot find a line where doScroll is being called

Comment: It's called by interval

Answer (score 1):

I create jsfiddle page for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/u32Nw/2/

I can see that it is working, but scrolling is not stopping.

```
    var t;
var scrolling = false;

// doScroll sets the position in which to auto pause.

function doScroll() {
    var $body = $("body"),
        $pause = $("#pause");
    $body.scrollTop($body.scrollTop() + 20);
    var pauseTop = $pause.offset().top;
    if (pauseTop >= 300 && pauseTop < 304 || pauseTop >= 4000 && pauseTop < 4004 || pauseTop >= 7500 && pauseTop < 7504) {
        clearScrollInterval();
    }
}

// scrollIt removes the interval for scrolling, pausing the scroll.

function clearScrollInterval() {
    clearInterval(t);
    scrolling = false;
    return;
    //        playPause()
}

//Stop/start on click
$("#pause").on("click", function () {
    clearScrollInterval();
    scrolling = !scrolling;
    t = setInterval(doScroll, 5);
});
```

This is exact same code, just refactored.

Try working from here. You need to refactor your code for debugging.

Comment: click on the fiddle link and test it yourself.

Comment: Sorry on mobile at the min. Can't test. Is it the autopause not working? In which case it's because the values are incorrect, pauseTop>= 300 && pauseTop<=304 should be pauseTop>= 300 && pauseTop<=319